# journey not putting a watermark on the data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, entry-criteria

when using automation studio audience to inject contacts into the journey, the journey is not doing a watermark and the same contact is receiving emails again and again instead of just sending to the new contacts added to the data extension.

everything else remaining same, if i use normal contact as an entry event, watermark works fine, only the newly added contacts receives emails.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a Query Activity in your Automation which is overwriting your Event Source DE.

Check the 'Update Type' in your Query Activity and confirm that it's set to 'Append' not 'Overwrite'. Overwriting will clear the high watermark.

Comment: there is no query activity in the journey

Comment: I know. You can't include query activities in journeys. I was referring to your event source DE that you are using to inject Contacts into your journey. Is this populated from a query?

Comment: @ShivamShukla, perhaps you can add a screenshot of the Automation you are using to inject contacts into the Journey? That would help.

Comment: checked with marketing cloud, with audience the functionality works this way only.